# Can't match item ids in Django two objects array with if condition

Tags: python, django, if-statement, django-templates, django-template-filters

My queryset code in view

```
'seats': Seats.objects.filter(bus=bid).order_by('seat_name'),
'booking': Booking.objects.filter(schedule=sid),
```

If condition code in template

```
{% for seat in seats %}
{% for book in booking %}
{% if seat.id == book.seat_id %}
match: {{seat.id}} ==  {{book.seat_id}}<br>
{% else %}
<input type="checkbox" name="checks[]" value="{{ seat.id }}"> {{ seat.seat_name }}{{ seat.seat_no }}
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

I need to disable the booked seats but the Django system can't check if condition and it shows all seats.

Comment: django giving correct output , show your models, and views

Answer (score 0):

I see there is one endfor, I'm not sure if it is an issue, or can you try something like if seat.id in booking: (by making a list of booked seat) or something like that removing the second for, it will also reduce runtime.